# Inner loops within Python from multi-dimensional JSON

Tags: python, json

I am writing an application that consumes a JSON web-service in Python. I have an outer loop and inner loop, my inner loop is pretty ugly; how can I codense this to function more like my outer loop?  By elegant, I mean performs the same functions without as many lines of code.

```
items = []
for sr in decoded2['Response']['ListOfServiceRequest']['ServiceRequest']:
    SRAddress = sr['SRAddress']
    Latitude = sr['Latitude']
    Longitude = sr['Longitude']
    ReasonCode = sr['ReasonCode']
    SRNumber = sr['SRNumber']
    FirstName = sr['FirstName']
    LastName = sr['LastName']
    ResolutionCode = sr['ResolutionCode']
    HomePhone = sr['HomePhone']
    CreatedDate = sr['CreatedDate']
    UpdatedDate = sr['UpdatedDate']
    BulkyItem = sr['ListOfLa311BulkyItem']
    ElectronicWaste = sr['ListOfLa311ElectronicWaste']
    MoveInMoveOut = sr['ListOfLa311MoveInMoveOut']
    IllegalDumping = sr['ListOfLa311IllegalDumpingPickup']
    ServiceNotComplete = sr['ListOfLa311ServiceNotComplete']
    BrushItems = sr['ListOfLa311BrushItemsPickup']
    Containers = sr['ListOfLa311Containers']
    MHA = sr['ListOfLa311MetalHouseholdAppliancesPickup']
    DeadAnimalRemoval = sr['ListOfLa311DeadAnimalRemoval']
    Manual = sr['ListOfLa311ManualPickup']
    CreatedDate = datetime.datetime.strptime(CreatedDate, "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S")
    UpdatedDate = datetime.datetime.strptime(UpdatedDate, "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S")
    print SRAddress



    for sr in ElectronicWaste:
            for ewastelocation in ElectronicWaste['La311ElectronicWaste']:
                                    locationewaste =  ewastelocation['CollectionLocation']
    for sr in ElectronicWaste:
            for ewastetype in ElectronicWaste['La311ElectronicWaste']:
                                    itemEwaste =  ewastetype['ElectronicWestType']
    for sr in ElectronicWaste:
            for ewastecount in ElectronicWaste['La311ElectronicWaste']:
                                    countEwaste =  ewastecount['ItemCount']
    for sr in ElectronicWaste:
            for typeewaste in ElectronicWaste['La311ElectronicWaste']:
                                    TypeEwaste =  typeewaste['Type']
    for sr in BulkyItem:
            for bulkycount in BulkyItem['BulkyItem']:
                                    countBulky =  bulkycount['BulkyItemCount']
    for sr in BulkyItem:
            for bulkyitem in BulkyItem['BulkyItem']:
                                    itemBulky =  bulkyitem['BulkyItemType']
    for sr in BulkyItem:
            for bulkylocation in BulkyItem['BulkyItem']:
                                    locationbulky =  bulkylocation['CollectionLocation']
    for sr in BulkyItem:
            for bulkytype in BulkyItem['BulkyItem']:
                                    typebulky =  bulkytype['Type']
    for sr in MHA:
            for mhalocation in MHA['La311MetalHouseholdAppliancesPickup']:
                                    locationmha =  mhalocation['CollectionLocation']
    for sr in MHA:
            for mhacount in MHA['La311MetalHouseholdAppliancesPickup']:
                                    countmha =  mhacount['HouseHoldItemCount']
    for sr in MHA:
            for mhaitem in MHA['La311MetalHouseholdAppliancesPickup']:
                                    itemmha =  mhaitem['HouseholdItem']
    for sr in MHA:
            for mhatype in MHA['La311MetalHouseholdAppliancesPickup']:
                                    typemha =  mhatype['Type']
    for sr in ServiceNotComplete:
            for missedservice in ServiceNotComplete['La311ServiceNotComplete']:
                                    servicemissed =  missedservice['MissedCollectionService']

    for sr in DeadAnimalRemoval:
            for dactype in DeadAnimalRemoval['DeadAnimalRemoval']:
                                    DARTYPE =  dactype['Type']
    for sr in DeadAnimalRemoval:
            for darlocation in DeadAnimalRemoval['DeadAnimalRemoval']:
                                    locationdar =  darlocation['CollectionLocation']
    for sr in DeadAnimalRemoval:
            for darcount in DeadAnimalRemoval['DeadAnimalRemoval']:
                                    countdar =  darcount['DACItemCount']
    for sr in DeadAnimalRemoval:
            for dartype in DeadAnimalRemoval['DeadAnimalRemoval']:
                                    typedac =  dartype['DACType']
    for sr in BrushItems:
            for brlocation in BrushItems['La311BrushItemsPickup']:
                                    locationbrush =  brlocation['CollectionLocation']
                                    print locationbrush
    for sr in BrushItems:
            for brtype in BrushItems['La311BrushItemsPickup']:
                                    typebrush =  brtype['BrushType']
                                    print typebrush
    for sr in BrushItems:
            for brcount in BrushItems['La311BrushItemsPickup']:
                                    countbrush =  brcount['BrushTypeCount']
                                    print countbrush
    for sr in BrushItems:
            for britem in BrushItems['La311BrushItemsPickup']:
                                    itembr =  britem['Type']
                                    print itembr
    for sr in MoveInMoveOut:
            for movelocation in MoveInMoveOut['La311MoveInMoveOut']:
                                    locationmove =  movelocation['CollectionLocation']
                                    print locationmove
    for sr in MoveInMoveOut:
            for movetype in MoveInMoveOut["La311MoveInMoveOut"]:
                                    typemove =  movetype['MoveType']
                                    print typemove

    for sr in MoveInMoveOut:
            for movetype in MoveInMoveOut["La311MoveInMoveOut"]:
                                    MOVETYPE =  movetype['Type']
                                    print MOVETYPE
    for sr in MoveInMoveOut:
            for moveitemcount in MoveInMoveOut["La311MoveInMoveOut":]:
                                    coutmove =  moveitemcount['ItemCount']
                                    print countmove
    for sr in Manual:
            for manuallocation in Manual["La311ManualPickup":]:
                                    locationmanual =  manuallocation['collectionLocation']
                                    print locationmanual
    for sr in Manual:
            for manualpickitem in Manual["La311ManualPickup":]:
                                    itempickmanual =  manualpickitem['ManualPickupItem']
                                    print itempickmanual
    for sr in Manual:
            for manualcount in Manual["La311ManualPickup"]:
                                    countmanual =  manualcount['ItemCount']
                                    print countmanual
    for sr in Manual:
            for typemanual in Manual["La311ManualPickup"]:
                                    MANUALTYPE =  typemanual['Type']
                                    print MANUALTYPE
    for sr in IllegalDumping:
            for illegallocaltion in IllegalDumping["La311IllegalDumpingPickup"]:
                                    locationillegal =  illegallocaltion['CollectionLocation']
                                    print locationillegal
    for sr in IllegalDumping:
            for illegaltype in IllegalDumping["La311IllegalDumpingPickup"]:
                                    typeillegal =  illegaltype['Type']
                                    print typeillegal`
```

```
"ListOfLa311BulkyItem": {
    "BulkyItem": [
        {
            "BulkyItemCount": "1",
            "BulkyItemType": "Basketball Set",
            "CollectionLocation": "",
            "IllegallyDumped": "Y",
            "OtherBulkyItem": "",
            "Type": "Bulky Items",
            "SpecialRule": "Y",
            "GatedCommunityMultifamilyDwelling": "",
            "MobileHomeSpace": "",
            "IllegalDumpCollectionLoc": "Alley",
            "LastUpdatedBy": "",
            "DriverFirstName": "",
            "DriverLastName": "",
            "ServiceDateRendered": "",
            "TruckNo": "",
            "ActiveStatus": "Y",
            "Name": "042220151543030741"
        },
        {
            "BulkyItemCount": "1",
            "BulkyItemType": "Bicycle",
            "CollectionLocation": "",
            "IllegallyDumped": "Y",
            "OtherBulkyItem": "",
            "Type": "Bulky Items",
            "SpecialRule": "Y",
            "GatedCommunityMultifamilyDwelling": "",
            "MobileHomeSpace": "",
            "IllegalDumpCollectionLoc": "Alley",
            "LastUpdatedBy": "",
            "DriverFirstName": "",
            "DriverLastName": "",
            "ServiceDateRendered": "",
            "TruckNo": "",
            "ActiveStatus": "Y",
            "Name": "042220151543030742"
        },
        {
            "BulkyItemCount": "1",
            "BulkyItemType": "Bird Cage (Plastic)",
            "CollectionLocation": "",
            "IllegallyDumped": "Y",
            "OtherBulkyItem": "",
            "Type": "Bulky Items",
            "SpecialRule": "Y",
            "GatedCommunityMultifamilyDwelling": "",
            "MobileHomeSpace": "",
            "IllegalDumpCollectionLoc": "Alley",
            "LastUpdatedBy": "",
            "DriverFirstName": "",
            "DriverLastName": "",
            "ServiceDateRendered": "",
            "TruckNo": "",
            "ActiveStatus": "Y",
            "Name": "042220151543030743"
        },
        {
            "BulkyItemCount": "1",
            "BulkyItemType": "Blinds",
            "CollectionLocation": "",
            "IllegallyDumped": "Y",
            "OtherBulkyItem": "",
            "Type": "Bulky Items",
            "SpecialRule": "Y",
            "GatedCommunityMultifamilyDwelling": "",
            "MobileHomeSpace": "",
            "IllegalDumpCollectionLoc": "Alley",
            "LastUpdatedBy": "",
            "DriverFirstName": "",
            "DriverLastName": "",
            "ServiceDateRendered": "",
            "TruckNo": "",
            "ActiveStatus": "Y",
            "Name": "042220151543030744"
        },
        {
            "BulkyItemCount": "1",
            "BulkyItemType": "Bookcase",
            "CollectionLocation": "",
            "IllegallyDumped": "Y",
            "OtherBulkyItem": "",
            "Type": "Bulky Items",
            "SpecialRule": "Y",
            "GatedCommunityMultifamilyDwelling": "",
            "MobileHomeSpace": "",
            "IllegalDumpCollectionLoc": "Alley",
            "LastUpdatedBy": "",
            "DriverFirstName": "",
            "DriverLastName": "",
            "ServiceDateRendered": "",
            "TruckNo": "",
            "ActiveStatus": "Y",
            "Name": "042220151543030745"
        },
        {
            "BulkyItemCount": "1",
            "BulkyItemType": "Door",
            "CollectionLocation": "",
            "IllegallyDumped": "Y",
            "OtherBulkyItem": "",
            "Type": "Bulky Items",
            "SpecialRule": "Y",
            "GatedCommunityMultifamilyDwelling": "",
            "MobileHomeSpace": "",
            "IllegalDumpCollectionLoc": "Alley",
            "LastUpdatedBy": "",
            "DriverFirstName": "",
            "DriverLastName": "",
            "ServiceDateRendered": "",
            "TruckNo": "",
            "ActiveStatus": "Y",
            "Name": "0422201515430307510"
        },
        {
            "BulkyItemCount": "1",
            "BulkyItemType": "Dresser",
            "CollectionLocation": "",
            "IllegallyDumped": "Y",
            "OtherBulkyItem": "",
            "Type": "Bulky Items",
            "SpecialRule": "Y",
            "GatedCommunityMultifamilyDwelling": "",
            "MobileHomeSpace": "",
            "IllegalDumpCollectionLoc": "Alley",
            "LastUpdatedBy": "",
            "DriverFirstName": "",
            "DriverLastName": "",
            "ServiceDateRendered": "",
            "TruckNo": "",
            "ActiveStatus": "Y",
            "Name": "0422201515430307511"
        },
        {
            "BulkyItemCount": "1",
            "BulkyItemType": "Fan",
            "CollectionLocation": "",
            "IllegallyDumped": "Y",
            "OtherBulkyItem": "",
            "Type": "Bulky Items",
            "SpecialRule": "Y",
            "GatedCommunityMultifamilyDwelling": "",
            "MobileHomeSpace": "",
            "IllegalDumpCollectionLoc": "Alley",
            "LastUpdatedBy": "",
            "DriverFirstName": "",
            "DriverLastName": "",
            "ServiceDateRendered": "",
            "TruckNo": "",
            "ActiveStatus": "Y",
            "Name": "0422201515430307512"
        },
        {
            "BulkyItemCount": "1",
            "BulkyItemType": "Fence (Wood)",
            "CollectionLocation": "",
            "IllegallyDumped": "Y",
            "OtherBulkyItem": "",
            "Type": "Bulky Items",
            "SpecialRule": "Y",
            "GatedCommunityMultifamilyDwelling": "",
            "MobileHomeSpace": "",
            "IllegalDumpCollectionLoc": "Alley",
            "LastUpdatedBy": "",
            "DriverFirstName": "",
            "DriverLastName": "",
            "ServiceDateRendered": "",
            "TruckNo": "",
            "ActiveStatus": "Y",
            "Name": "0422201515430307513"
        },
        {
            "BulkyItemCount": "1",
            "BulkyItemType": "File Cabinet (Wood)",
            "CollectionLocation": "",
            "IllegallyDumped": "Y",
            "OtherBulkyItem": "",
            "Type": "Bulky Items",
            "SpecialRule": "Y",
            "GatedCommunityMultifamilyDwelling": "",
            "MobileHomeSpace": "",
            "IllegalDumpCollectionLoc": "Alley",
            "LastUpdatedBy": "",
            "DriverFirstName": "",
            "DriverLastName": "",
            "ServiceDateRendered": "",
            "TruckNo": "",
            "ActiveStatus": "Y",
            "Name": "0422201515430307514"
        },
        {
            "BulkyItemCount": "1",
            "BulkyItemType": "Cabinet",
            "CollectionLocation": "",
            "IllegallyDumped": "Y",
            "OtherBulkyItem": "",
            "Type": "Bulky Items",
            "SpecialRule": "Y",
            "GatedCommunityMultifamilyDwelling": "",
            "MobileHomeSpace": "",
            "IllegalDumpCollectionLoc": "Alley",
            "LastUpdatedBy": "",
            "DriverFirstName": "",
            "DriverLastName": "",
            "ServiceDateRendered": "",
            "TruckNo": "",
            "ActiveStatus": "Y",
            "Name": "042220151543030756"
        },
        {
            "BulkyItemCount": "1",
            "BulkyItemType": "Carpet",
            "CollectionLocation": "",
            "IllegallyDumped": "Y",
            "OtherBulkyItem": "",
            "Type": "Bulky Items",
            "SpecialRule": "Y",
            "GatedCommunityMultifamilyDwelling": "",
            "MobileHomeSpace": "",
            "IllegalDumpCollectionLoc": "Alley",
            "LastUpdatedBy": "",
            "DriverFirstName": "",
            "DriverLastName": "",
            "ServiceDateRendered": "",
            "TruckNo": "",
            "ActiveStatus": "Y",
            "Name": "042220151543030757"
        },
        {
            "BulkyItemCount": "1",
            "BulkyItemType": "Decorating Item",
            "CollectionLocation": "",
            "IllegallyDumped": "Y",
            "OtherBulkyItem": "",
            "Type": "Bulky Items",
            "SpecialRule": "Y",
            "GatedCommunityMultifamilyDwelling": "",
            "MobileHomeSpace": "",
            "IllegalDumpCollectionLoc": "Alley",
            "LastUpdatedBy": "",
            "DriverFirstName": "",
            "DriverLastName": "",
            "ServiceDateRendered": "",
            "TruckNo": "",
            "ActiveStatus": "Y",
            "Name": "042220151543030758"
        },
        {
            "BulkyItemCount": "1",
            "BulkyItemType": "Desk",
            "CollectionLocation": "",
            "IllegallyDumped": "Y",
            "OtherBulkyItem": "",
            "Type": "Bulky Items",
            "SpecialRule": "Y",
            "GatedCommunityMultifamilyDwelling": "",
            "MobileHomeSpace": "",
            "IllegalDumpCollectionLoc": "Alley",
            "LastUpdatedBy": "",
            "DriverFirstName": "",
            "DriverLastName": "",
            "ServiceDateRendered": "",
            "TruckNo": "",
            "ActiveStatus": "Y",
            "Name": "042220151543030759"
        }
    ]
```

Comment: What is this actually *for*? Most of your loops don't seem to actually *do* anything, so why bother having them?

Comment: I have a JSON with multi-dimensional arrays. My request can return one or 300 + objects per service request type, i.e. BulkyItems, ElectronicWaste, etc.  When I use the same logic that I have built to loop through decoded2 I receive key errors.  The trick to this loop is to loop through all of LA311xxx items and grab the specified info i.e. type.  So there can be for instance 3 LA3111 CollectionLocations, all need to be looped through and written to a database.

Comment: Could you add an example of the JSON data?

Comment: I added an example of the JSON for a multi-dimensional service request of Bulky Item pick up.

Answer (score 2):

After adding `{}}` I loaded your sample JSON as

```
decoded2 = json.loads(txt)
```

The key to 'iterating' through this structure is to recognize when you are working with a dictionary, and when it is a list.  A dictionary is accessed by key word.  The `.get()` method is handy when you aren't sure about the key.

A list is accessed either with an index number or a loop.

I can explore it with

```
In [712]: listof=decoded2.get('ListOfLa311BulkyItem')

In [713]: if listof:   
    # this would be None if it wasn't a valid key
    items = listof.get('BulkyItem')
   .....:     

In [714]: len(items)
Out[714]: 14
```

I can collect a specific key for each item with a list comprehension (just a compact way of iterating through a list)

```
In [715]: [item.get('BulkyItemType') for item in items]
Out[715]: 
['Basketball Set',
 'Bicycle',
 'Bird Cage (Plastic)',
...
 'Carpet',
 'Decorating Item',
 'Desk']
```

Again, I would get a list of `None` if I'd mistyped the key.

A single item is accessed with

```
In [716]: items[0]
Out[716]: 
{'Name': '042220151543030741',
 'CollectionLocation': '',
 'ServiceDateRendered': '',
 'IllegalDumpCollectionLoc': 'Alley',
 'Type': 'Bulky Items',
 'ActiveStatus': 'Y',
 'LastUpdatedBy': '',
 'IllegallyDumped': 'Y',
 'TruckNo': '',
 ...
 'DriverLastName': ''}
```

I can collect several attributes as a list of tuples, with

```
In [726]: x=[(item['BulkyItemType'],item['BulkyItemCount']) for item in items]
```

And on SO you were trying to turn such a list into a structured numpy array

```
In [727]: np.array(x,dtype=[('name','a20'),('count','i')])
Out[727]: 
array([(b'Basketball Set', 1), (b'Bicycle', 1),
       (b'Bird Cage (Plastic)', 1), (b'Blinds', 1), (b'Bookcase', 1),
       (b'Door', 1), (b'Dresser', 1), (b'Fan', 1), (b'Fence (Wood)', 1),
       (b'File Cabinet (Wood)', 1), (b'Cabinet', 1), (b'Carpet', 1),
       (b'Decorating Item', 1), (b'Desk', 1)], 
      dtype=[('name', 'S20'), ('count', '<i4')])
```

I can access the fields of such an array by name, and do math on the numeric field

```
In [733]: a=np.array(x,dtype=[('name','a20'),('count','i')])

In [734]: a['name']
Out[734]: 
array([b'Basketball Set', b'Bicycle', b'Bird Cage (Plastic)', b'Blinds',
       b'Bookcase', b'Door', b'Dresser', b'Fan', b'Fence (Wood)',
       b'File Cabinet (Wood)', b'Cabinet', b'Carpet', b'Decorating Item',
       b'Desk'], 
      dtype='|S20')

In [735]: a['count'].sum()
Out[735]: 14
```